# jQuery - Deleting 'corresponding' items

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list with two different kinds of items, product-x and product-y.

When the user deletes product-x I need it's equivalent product-y to also delete and vise-versa.

I've tried this a couple of different ways but nothing seems to be working. I appreciate any help!

---

JS

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-item', function(e) {
    $(this).parents('.product-x').delay(500).remove();
    $(this).parents('.product-y').delay(500).remove();
});
```

---

CSS

```
.product-x, .product-y{
    width:100px;
    height:50px;
    margin:10px;
}

.product-x{
    border:red 1px solid;
}

.product-y{
    border:navy 1px solid;
}
```

---

HTML

```
<div id="product-x-wrapper"> 
    <div class="product-x">1 
          <button class="delete-item">x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="product-x">2
          <button class="delete-item">x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="product-x">3
          <button class="delete-item">x</button>
        </div>
    </div>
<div id="product-y-wrapper"> 
        <div class="product-y">1
          <button class="delete-item">x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="product-y">2
          <button class="delete-item">x</button>
        </div>
        <div class="product-y">3
          <button class="delete-item">x</button>
        </div>
</div>
```

Comment: when you say "sibling" do you mean the one with the same number? (e.g. 1,2 or 3)

Comment: You are not using the term `sibling` correctly.  In this context, a `sibling` is ANY element that is at the same DOM level / adjacent to the element in question.  You want the same "product y" item deleted, presumably - if it's #2, then delete the #2 product y?

Comment: By 'sibling' do you really mean corresponding?

Comment: Just add an identical class to the x and y. Then remove all the elements with the class of the clicked element.

Comment: you should probably just add an id tag with the number in it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, I would add a `data-product-id` to each element so you can find them without relying on the human-readable label:

```
<div id="product-wrapper">
  <div class="product-x" data-product-id="1">1 <button...></div>
  <div class="product-x" data-product-id="2">2 <button...></div>
  <div class="product-x" data-product-id="3">3 <button...></div>
  <div class="product-y" data-product-id="1">1 <button...></div>
  <div class="product-y" data-product-id="2">2 <button...></div>
  <div class="product-y" data-product-id="3">3 <button...></div>
</div>
```

Then you can remove the matching sibling like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-item', function(e) {
  var id = $(this).parent().data('product-id');
  $("#product-wrapper").find('div[data-product-id="' + id + '"]').delay(500).remove();
});
```

**EDIT:** Since you've changed the question to separate the products into two wrappers, you can use this approach, but just remove things from both places, like so:

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-item', function(e) {
  var id = $(this).parent().data('product-id');
  $("#product-x-wrapper").find('div[data-product-id="' + id + '"]').delay(500).remove();
  $("#product-y-wrapper").find('div[data-product-id="' + id + '"]').delay(500).remove();
});
```

Comment: this is the right answer he should just be using proper ids

Comment: but you probably just  get rid of the data and just do id='product-x-1'

Comment: This is great, but how would I solve if the products are contained in two different wrappers?

Comment: just tried to run this and it doesn't seem to work. appreciate any help: https://jsfiddle.net/dzcLkwwp/

Comment: @unfollow - What do you mean by two different wrappers? If this is important, update your question to include that detail.

Comment: It should be:  var id = $(this).parent().data('product-id');  -> https://jsfiddle.net/dzcLkwwp/1/

Comment: @j08691 updated the example to reflect the question better. whole question has been abstracted to simplify things.

Answer (score 1):

Without any additional markup or classes, you can use jQuery's [`.index()`](https://api.jquery.com/index/) function to delete the corresponding item:

```js
$('.delete-item').each(function() {
  $(this).parent().data('idx', $(this).parent().index())
}).click(function() {
  var idx = $(this).parent().data('idx');
  $('div > div').each(function() {
    if ($(this).data('idx') === idx) $(this).remove()
  })
})
```

```css
.product-x,
.product-y {
  width: 100px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 10px;
}
.product-x {
  border: red 1px solid;
}
.product-y {
  border: navy 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="product-x-wrapper">
  <div class="product-x">1
    <button class="delete-item">x</button>
  </div>
  <div class="product-x">2
    <button class="delete-item">x</button>
  </div>
  <div class="product-x">3
    <button class="delete-item">x</button>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="product-y-wrapper">
  <div class="product-y">1
    <button class="delete-item">x</button>
  </div>
  <div class="product-y">2
    <button class="delete-item">x</button>
  </div>
  <div class="product-y">3
    <button class="delete-item">x</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

you should probably just add an id to it so you can look it up by id, but assuming they are all corresponding and in order you can do this

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-item', function(e) {
    var producty = $(this).parent();
    var index = $(".product-y").index(producty );

    $('.product-x:eq('+ index +')').remove();
}
```

this also allows your html to differ

Answer (score 0):

The way I would do this is grab the value of the product-y you have clicked on using jquerys .val().  Then you can loop through all your product-x's and once you have found a matching .val then you can delete that.

I can write you some code if you need but hopefully this is enough to help you understand how to solve it.

e/ - Pauls way is more elegant use that :D

Comment: "I can write you some code if you need" - That's typically what an answer should include.

Comment: @j08691 this is a rather simple question, I assumed a solid explanation might be more beneficial to try and code himself that to simply do it for him, Point taken though.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Note: You should use some sort of DOM Handle which can be accessed using a selector, like `class`,`id`,`data- attributes`, `name` etc.

now if you still want to go this way, which I strongly discourage, then you can use the `:contains` selector.

```
$(document).on('click', '.delete-item', function(e) {
    $content = $(this).parent().html();
    $(this).parents('.product-x').delay(500).remove();
    $(".product-y:contains("+$content+")).delay(500).remove();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Slightly different take:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div data-product="one" class="one product-x">1 
  <button class="delete-item">x</button>
</div>
<div data-product="two" class="two product-x">2
  <button class="delete-item">x</button>
</div>
<div data-product="three" class="three product-x">3
  <button class="delete-item">x</button>
</div>
<div data-product="one" class="one product-y">1
  <button class="delete-item">x</button>
</div>
<div data-product="two" class="two product-y">2
  <button class="delete-item">x</button>
</div>
<div data-product="three" class="three product-y">3
  <button class="delete-item">x</button>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
$('.delete-item').on('click',function(e){
    var theProduct = $(this).parent().data('product');
    var theElements = $('div[data-product="' + theProduct + '"]');
    theElements.delay(500).fadeOut();
})
</script>
```

fadeOut() is sexier ;)